# How do I print the characters "\n" instead of whitespace using python and C?

Tags: python, c, whitespace

I want to print the specific characters \n in python and C language. Of course its the newline character so every time I say print("\n") or printf("\n") it simply prints whitespace.
What I want are the specific characters \ and n as the output.
Could someone please help with this?

Comment: Don't know about python, but for C you need to escape the backslash, so `"\\n"`

Comment: Each question should be about only one language. Asking a single question about both Python and C prevents us from closing it as a duplicate of a question only about Python or a question only about C, even though we have both duplicates already in the knowledge base separately; and for that reason, it makes the question eligible for close as "too broad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C you need to add another "\" to your code like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
  printf("\\n");
}
```

For Python you can use [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)

```
>>> string = "\n"
>>> print(repr(string))
'\n'
```

Comment: `repr` does more than just add slashes.

Comment: @gre_gor i know, repr represents an object as a string, but here they want to know about backslashes only.

Comment: OP wants to print `\n` not `'\n'`.

Comment: Thank you but yeah with the python part, I want \n not '\n'

Comment: @Leandra if you want only \n you can use print("\\n") it will get you \n not '\n'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `repr()` to represent a raw string.

`print(repr('\n'))`

Comment: `repr` does more than just add slashes.